# Separating list into divs to show only one at a time

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

My question is on seperating a list of Questions into seperate divs (using javascript/html/c#). How the program works at the moment is there is a main view for the quiz, which displays the content section and once completed hides that partial and shows the quiz partial view.

Currently this displays all the questions in order formatted like so
(imagine a quiz with only 2 questions)

Q#1

### -(multiple choice)

-

Previousbtn      NextBtn

Q#2

### -(multiple choice)

-

Previousbtn      Finish

What i'm trying to do is display only one question at a time by (presumably) seperating each question into its own div and showing/hiding them as needed (on btn click of Next or previous).

I've hit a wall yesterday afternoon and today so anygeneral guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code, like how are you trying to achieve this? You can use javascript or just plain CSS and HTML to do this but I wouldn't make any suggestions until the requirement is clear.

Comment: hi, sorry to be vague but its company source code so im hesitant to post much. atm in the quiz partial view there is something like this-

foreach (var question in model.quiz) { logic for what should be displayed }

but i think i'll need to somehow create a div in this foreach for each question in the quiz and assign it a unique id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Previous Next functions you can use the same as Aren, but to answer the question posted, about separating a list use the following

You would have the same script as mentioned

```js
    var index = 0;
    var n = $("div.quiz-container").length;
    var a = n - 1

     $(".quiz-container:first").addClass("active").show();
    if (index == 0) {
      $("#prev").prop("disabled", true);
    }
    $("#next").on("click", function() {
      index++;
      $(".quiz-container.active").removeClass('active').hide();
      $(".quiz-container").eq(index).addClass('active').show();
      if (index == 0) {
        $("#prev").prop("disabled", true);
      } else if (index != 0) {
        $("#prev").prop("disabled", false);
      }
      if (index != a) {
        $("#next").prop("disabled", false);
      } else if (index == a) {
        $("#next").prop("disabled", true);
      }
    });
    $("#prev").on("click", function() {
      index--;
      $(".quiz-container.active").removeClass('active').hide();
      $(".quiz-container").eq(index).addClass('active').show();
      if (index == 0) {
        $("#prev").prop("disabled", true);
      } else if (index != 0) {
        $("#prev").prop("disabled", false);
      }
      if (index != a) {
        $("#next").prop("disabled", false);
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quiz-container active">
  <p>Q: Question 1?</p>
  <ul>
    <li>choice1</li>
    <li>choice2</li>
    <li>choice3</li>
    <li>choice4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="quiz-container" style="display:none">
  <p>Q: Question 2?</p>
  <ul>
    <li>choice1</li>
    <li>choice2</li>
    <li>choice3</li>
    <li>choice4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="quiz-container" style="display:none">
  <p>Q: Question 3?</p>
  <ul>
    <li>choice1</li>
    <li>choice2</li>
    <li>choice3</li>
    <li>choice4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

**But in your view's foreach loop you would have:**

```
foreach (var question in model.quiz) { 
 <div class="quiz-container">
      <h1>@question.QuestionTitle</h1>
      <ul>
           foreach (var answer in question.Answers) {
           <li>@answer</li>
           }
      </ul>
 </div>
 }

<button id="next">Next</button>
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
```

So you can have a varied amount of answers and varied amount of question. Hope this helps.

P.S you need to edit the code according to your model

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, this will be helpful. is there a way of using your function with  .hide() and .show() instead of css? this seems to be the way our project manager wants it done

Comment: @bjjrolls also see the JSFiddle showing a working version of JQuery, obviously it needs to have rules etc put in

Comment: @bjjrolls JSFiddle now has code to ensure buttons are enabled/disabled when appropriate

Answer (score 1):

This is just a sample code, you can get some knowledge and add your extra logic to achieve

```js
$(function(){
 var index = 0;
 $(".quiz-container").addClass("inactive");
 $(".quiz-container:first").addClass("active");
 $("#next").on("click", function(){
  index++;
  $(".quiz-container.active").removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
  $(".quiz-container").eq(index).removeClass("inactive").addClass(active);
 })
 $("#prev").on("click", function(){
  index--;
  $(".quiz-container.active").removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
  $(".quiz-container").eq(index).removeClass("inactive").addClass(active);
 })
});
```

```css
.active {
 display: block;
}
.inactive {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz-container">
<p>Q: Question?</p>
<ul>
<li>choice1</li>
<li>choice2</li>
<li>choice3</li>
<li>choice4</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="quiz-container">
<p>Q: Question?</p>
<ul>
<li>choice1</li>
<li>choice2</li>
<li>choice3</li>
<li>choice4</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="quiz-container">
<p>Q: Question?</p>
<ul>
<li>choice1</li>
<li>choice2</li>
<li>choice3</li>
<li>choice4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```